# How can I export SDL Tridion 2011 sp1 CMS search results to excel?

Tags: 2011-sp1

How can I export SDL Tridion 2011 sp1 CMS search results to excel ?

Comment: Can you confirm your full requirement (e.g. is this a one-off, regular, static search) and what you've tried already (have you tried anything? have you read any articles that are/are not helpful - so we don't just have you try the same thing)?

Answer (score 3):

your question is very vague, and you should provide some more details like what you want to save etc.

But, as a possible response, this looks like a core services job.

You can create a tridion custom page with a search box, and you can put a small web app behind that which performs a search using core services. An example of how to do this can be found here http://erichuiza.blogspot.be/2012/06/performing-search-queries-with-core.html)
The results of that search query is an xml document. Based on what you need, you can simply loop over these elements, and store the available data in a csv file (that excel can open). Additionally, if you need more information, you can loop over all returned items, open them individually, and get all the data you might need.
Note that this last option might take some time, if you have a lot of results.

Comment: Thanks Harald for your inputs, This is what I needed. I have one query here is it possible to extend the existing search functionality of tridion using GUI extensions to add a "Download Excel" button which will generate and download the excel containing the search results ?

Comment: I think it could be done with a GUI extension, using: $display.getView().properties.controls.list in your extension js,  to get the result elements and pass like a param to an aspx and finally export to excel using some .net library (there are a lot to do this).

Comment: Not exactly sure what is the use case for persisting into an excel, but you can also save the search query as a "virtual folder" in CME and then you be able to see what exists for that search query dynamically when you click to open the folder

Comment: Adding to what @Vipin states, as soon as you have a Virtual Folder, you can access that using the Core Service (like any other folder) and save its results (which is the search query results) into an Excel sheet in an application (or Custom Page for that matter).

Answer (score 2):

We have implemented an **Excel Export GUI extension**.

The GUI extension exports all the contents of Organizational items (Folders, Virtual Folders, Structure Groups, Keywords).

It also **Exports Search results** and the items related to (tagged with) a keyword.

The information provided in the Excel is the same that the Tridion GUI uses (GetlistItems). In one hand, this makes it very fast and useful for all Tridion implementations; in the other hand, the information is limited.

Nevertheless, it has been very useful to us.