# Is there an extension that can Export search result To Excel for Web 8?

Tags: web8.5, gui-extensions, search

I want to export search result on CME to an excel file.

I found [`Export To Excel`](https://appstore.sdl.com/web-content-management/app/export-to-excel/644/) on SDL AppStore, but it's Supported products is blank and I cannot download it.

Can `Export To Excel` download search result?

Is `Export To Excel` available on SDL Web 8?

I also read the following [post](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/11747/how-can-i-export-sdl-tridion-2011-sp1-cms-search-results-to-excel), and a respondent mentions there is an extension which can exports search result on Tridion 2011.

Is there any similar extension for SDL Web8?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can also try the `Export Item List` alchemy plugin. It can be downloaded from here: https://www.alchemywebstore.com/plugins/Export-Item-List

If you want to customize or extend it the code is also available at https://github.com/saurabhgangwar/Alchemy.Plugins/tree/master/Alchemy.Plugins.ExportItemList

Comment: Thanks.This is good extension.But I need 'Location(folder's path)' of search result view, so I'll try customize the extension.

Comment: I found it's possible to customize the extension by editing JS file. But I'm afraid Alchemy's Terms and Conditions doesn't allow customizing programs.So could you write clearly that it's OK to customize the Extension to Alchemy's Plugin page, if there's no problem?

Comment: Yeah, The code is public on the GitHub. Please feel free to customize it.

Comment: Thank you for kindness.But according to Alchemy's Terms & Conditions, it doesn't seem to allow modify downloaded programs. So I'd like you to write clearly 'Export Item List can be customized freely' to Alchemy plugin page, otherwise customizing Export Item List can be license violation.

Comment: Please ask a Question to Alchemy Support or here at Stack Exchange. I am sure the Alchemy Team will help you with this and the answer might help others. Personally I don't see any issue with this. Below is what I would do: 1. Get The Source Code from GitHub 2. Customize it 3.Build and Generate A4T file 4. Install the extension by dragging the A4T file in your CMS Alchemy Install Page.

Comment: I understand you allow customize your source code, but according to GitHub's policy, anyone is not allowed to modify the source code if any license is not specified.So I'd appreciate it if you specify a license (e.g. Open source license) to allow customizing on your GitHub repository, just for legal issue.GitHub's Web page about licensing is following.
https://help.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/licensing-a-repository

Comment: Added the license: https://github.com/saurabhgangwar/Alchemy.Plugins/blob/master/LICENSE

Answer (score 2):

I tried to to download 'Export to Excel' from the App Store too and got the following message:

[image]

---

We have a version of 'Export to Excel' working on Tridion 8.5 at my current client. Unfortunately this isn't my code, so I can't just share it, so I suggest that you contact SDL Support to get a version from the App Store.

However, although the 'Export to Excel' button was available on the Search Results screen, nothing happened when I clicked on it.

I then saved the search results into a Virtual Search Folder, but the 'Export to Excel' tool gave an error when I clicked on it.

[image]

I then created a bundle and added all of the items from the Virtual Folder into the Bundle and the 'Export to Excel' functionality worked and gave me a CSV file.

You could probably miss out the middle step here (creating the Virtual Search Folder) and just add the search results to a Bundle and then use 'Export to Excel'.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I asked about the 'Export To Excel' to SDL Support and SDL Community, but I couldn't know how to download it and whether is works.

Comment: Did SDL Support reply?

Comment: SDL Support just suggests asking about the extension to SDL Community.

Comment: Well, that’s not very helpful of them! They can’t even supply you with the source code or point you in the direction of the git repo?

Comment: SDL support only shared community's similar issue page.